# How to identify if an expression is 'method invocation'?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, antlr

Consider the method invocation expression below :

```
foo(1, 2, bar())
```

The function `foo` takes three arguments, where the third argument is the value returned by the function, `bar`. Now suppose, I need to find out whether the expression inside the parentheses is a *method invocation* or not. For the above cases, I should report `bar()`.

For this case,

```
foo(1, foobar(0, 1), A.staticMethod(1)),
```

I should report `foobar(0, 1)` and `A.staticMethod(1)`, where `A` is a class having the static function,  `staticMethod(int)`. Is there any way or a fail-safe regex that will be applicable for this case ?

Following are the other cases which should be reported as well :

```
new A().foo()
a.foo()        // A a = new A();
a.bar().field  // bar() returns an object here
```

I am open to using any parsing APIs like `ANTLR` as well.

Also, as mentioned in one of the comments, I want to clarify that the only input is the expression and nothing else, not the source code (and hence, no comments or something else I should ignore).

Comment: I think you could tell the start of the expression by looking for an identifier and then an open paren -- though you'd run into problems with "code" in comments or strings. And you wouldn't be able to find the expression's end, at least not easily. So really the answer is, you need a parser. But if you're asking how to write one, this question is too broad, and if you're asking us to provide a link to one, it's off topic as a request for an external resource. Either way, this question seems OT to me. You could also compile the Java and examine the bytecode.

Comment: Is `a.bar().field` a method invocation?

Comment: I am already working on a parser using ANTLR. I have come to a point where I need to extract _method-invocation_ expression when being passed as an argument, but the Java8 grammar is somehow not allowing me to do this. I can find _method-invocation_ expressions normally, but not when being passed as an argument to another method. @yshavit

Comment: Yes. Good example ! @saka1029

Comment: @saka1029 but make sure you don't parse `"a.bar().field"` as one!

Comment: _'problems with "code" in comments or strings'_ This won't happen given the way I am parsing the source code.

Comment: Is lambda expression `x -> foo(x)` a method invocation?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're asking us to debug your grammar without even seeing it... which is also OT. I'm not trying to be harsh here, but you're asking for help on a pretty big thing, and not giving us much to go on.

Comment: Here, start reading : https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4#L1104 There is no scope to debug this grammar, I am just saying its not possible to take help from grammar any further. You will realize after you see the rule mentioning `argumentList`. @yshavit

Comment: Let's not talk about lambda expressions here, shall we ? @saka1029

Comment: How about `new int[] {s.length()}`?

Comment: Report `length()`. Other things aside,  is that your way of saying that it's just not possible or something ? @saka1029

Comment: `argumentList` in that grammar is just a list of `expression`s. If you are able to identify method invocations in expressions, so should you in argument list. Maybe you just forgot to recurse into the argument list's expressions upon encountering a method invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no syntax errors in the input, you can simply define a method invocation as an identifier (`[A-Za-z_]\w*`) followed by a parenthesized set of arguments, with the added condition that it is not preceded by te keyword `new` (since your syntax supports instance creation).

```java
public static List<String> methodCalls(String input) {
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*[A-Za-z_]\\w*\\s*\\(");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        int start = m.start();
        int end = m.end();

        if (start == 3 && input.startsWith("new") 
            || start > 3 && input.substring(start-4, start).matches("\\Wnew")) {
            // if it is preceded by the word new, it is not a method call
            continue;
        }

        int pairs = 1;
        while (end < input.length() && pairs > 0) {
            // can't just stop at the next ')'
            // since parentheses may be nested
            char c = input.charAt(end);
            if (c == '(') pairs++;
            else if (c == ')') pairs--;
            end++;
        }

        matches.add(input.substring(start, end));
    }

    return matches;
}
```